# upper bound for $\frac{ax}{x-2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I need an upper bound for 
$$\frac{ax}{x-2}$$
I know that $1\leq a< 2$ and $x\geq 0$.

This upper bound can include just $a$ and constant numbers not $x$.

thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no upper bound. What happens when $x$ goes to 2?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+}\frac{ax}{x-2}=+\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

And a picture for the graphical learners.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For $2>x \ge 0$, you get a negative value, and for $x>2$ you will see that the value gradually reduces.  What happens when $x \to 2$? Consider LHL and RHL.